# Пустой ResultSet

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Проблема максимально проста:
Данный код возвращает пустой ResultSet, а именно выводит на экран 0.
Причем, запуск такого же SQL запроса непосредственно из MySQL CLI возвращает ответ, так как запись с таким username существует.
Подключение к DB происходит, так как другие запросы вроде `insert` работают.

```
Statement statement = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db", "user", "pass").createStatement();

ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery("SELECT `token` FROM tokens WHERE `username`='" + username + "'");
        System.out.println(result.getFetchSize());
```

Comment: лишние кавычки вокруг `token` и `username`

Comment: Прошу прощения за английский. This is unsafe and SQL injection prone. Do _not_ do it like this (with concatenation). Use parameterized prepared statements instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getFetchSize()` не возвращает общее количество записей в `ResultSet`, он возвращает количество полученных/прочитанных записей (надеюсь понимаете разницу).

*fetch* - это что-то вроде кэширования, чтобы не дергать каждый раз БД. Результат возвращается в виде блоков, например JDBC от Oracle по умолчанию сразу читаются 10 записей. Размер *fetch* можно менять, например через `setFetchSize()`

Чтобы получить количество записей надо немного по другому:

```
result.last(); //позиционируемся на последнюю запись
int resultCount = result.getRow(); //количество записей
```